# Proof about the uniqueness of the Laplace transform in a general setting

Tags: analysis, reference-request, laplace-transform

Reading the book of *A Graduate Course on Statistical Inference* of Bing Li and Jogesh Babu in page 43 it is asserted that

$$
\left(\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}^k:\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}g(t)e^{\theta \cdot t}d\nu(t)=0\right)\implies g=0,\quad\nu\text{-a.e.}\tag1
$$

where in the LHS $\nu$ is an arbitrary $\sigma$-finite measure and $g$ is integrable respect to this measure. The book says that the implication is consequence of the uniqueness of the Laplace transform, however I don't found a proof about this uniqueness in the general setting of an arbitrary measure.

Can someone give me a proof, or reference that includes a proof, of the uniqueness of the Laplace transform in this context? Thank you in advance.

---

ADDITION: letting $\theta\in \mathbb C ^k$ it can be seen that if $t\mapsto g(t)e^{\theta \cdot t}$ is $\nu $-integrable in some open subset $\Theta $ the function defined by

$$
f(\theta ):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}g(t)e^{\theta \cdot t}d\nu(t)\tag2
$$

is analytic in $\Theta $ (i.e. it is complex differentiable). Therefore it follows easily that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}g(t)e^{\theta \cdot t}d\nu(t)=0\implies \int_{\mathbb{R}^k}g(t)p(t)e^{\theta \cdot t}d\nu(t)=0\tag3
$$

for any arbitrary polynomial $p$ (of real or complex coefficients). Maybe this can be used to prove (1), however I dont see by now how.

Comment: I presume you need conditions on $g$. Perhaps the Post/Widder inversion formula might shed some light?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, I forget to say that $g$ must be $\nu$ integrable, I will add this to the question. I took a look at Widder but it used Riemann Stieltjes integrals and I will need to re-read about these forget topics, so I think someone can now a more generalized proof in a measure theoretic setting

Comment: If $g \cdot p$ are also integrable then more must be true of $g$ surely?

Comment: @copper.hat maybe this is the way. The analyticity of $f$ show us that $gp$ is also integrable for arbitrary $p$. But in first place in the book $g$ is just assumed to be integrable. Choosing $\theta=0$ it gives that $\int gp d\nu=0$ for all polynomials $p$ (if Im not wrong)

Comment: I'm not sure how you reach the $gp$ integrable for all polynomials without additional conditions.

Comment: @copper.hat because $\int g(t)p(t) e^{\theta \cdot t}d\nu(t)=0$ for all $\theta\in \Bbb R^k$, so letting $\theta=0$ you have it

Comment: Even with the basic Laplace transform you need stronger conditions than integrability of $g$ to get analyticity of the transform.

Comment: @copper.hat the previous lemma of the book says that if $g(t)e^{\theta\cdot t}$ is integrable for all $\theta\in\Theta$ respect to $\nu$ and $\Theta$ open, then $f(\theta):=\int g(t)e^{\theta\cdot t}d\nu(t)$ is analytic and the derivatives can be taken inside the integral. It gives a reference for a proof. I checked the reference (page 49 of Lehman and Romano 2005) and seems right.

Comment: It may be true, but their proof is a bit hand wavy for me and I do not have time to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a beautiful proof in the book *Decomposition of Multivariate Distributions* of Roger Cuppens that I will essentially reproduce here for completeness. We start from the point that $\theta \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^k}g(t)e^{\theta \cdot t}d\nu(t)$ is an analytic function in the whole $\mathbb{C}^k$, and so it is zero everywhere because its zero in some open subset. Then for any trigonometric polynomial $T$ we have that  $\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}Tg\, d\nu=0$, so

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}T\,d\mu^+=\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}T\,d\mu^-\tag1
$$

where $d\mu^+:=g^+\mathop{}\!d \nu,\,d\mu^-:=g^-\mathop{}\!d \nu$ where $g^+:=\max\{g,0\},\,g^-:=-\min\{g,0\}$, so $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are non-negative finite measures. Also we will use $|\mu|:=\mu^++\mu^-$, that is, $|\mu|$ is the total variation of $\mu$.

Let $K$ any compact set, then $\mathbf{1}_{K}$ can be approximated by continuous functions with compact support, as the continuous functions are dense in $L^1(|\mu|)$ so, for arbitrarily small $\epsilon >0$ suppose that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}|f-\mathbf{1}_{K}|\,d|\mu|<\epsilon$ for some continuous function $f$ with values in $[0,1]$. Now define a periodic version of $f$, namely $f_p=f$ in the support of $f$ such that $f_p$ have period $p$ in every orthogonal direction of $\mathbb{R}^k$. Then clearly $f_p\to  f$ pointwise as $p\to \infty $, and due to the Stone-Weierstrass theorem for every $f_p$ there is a trigonometric polynomial $T_p$ such that $\|T_p-f_p\|_{\infty }<p^{-1}$. Therefore if $P\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ is a cube of side lengths $p$ so there is a full period of  $T_p$ there and we choose it such that $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subset P$, then $\|\mathbf{1}_{P}T_p-f\|_\infty <p^{-1}$.

Then for $p^{-1}<\epsilon $ we have that
$$
-\epsilon \mu^+(\mathbb{R}^k)+\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}f d\mu^+\leqslant \mu^+(K)\leqslant \epsilon \mu^+(\mathbb{R}^k)+\int_{\mathbb{R}^k}f d\mu^+\\
\implies -2\epsilon\, \mu^+(\mathbb{R}^k)+\int_{P}T_p d\mu^+\leqslant \mu^+(K)\leqslant 2\epsilon\, \mu^+(\mathbb{R}^k)+\int_{P}T_p d\mu^+\tag2
$$

As the same holds for $\mu^-$ then

$$
-2\epsilon \,|\mu|(\mathbb{R}^k)+\int_{P}T_p\,d\mu\leqslant \mu(K)\leqslant 2\epsilon \,|\mu|(\mathbb{R}^k)+\int_{P}T_p\,d\mu\\
\iff -2\epsilon \,|\mu|(\mathbb{R}^k)-\int_{P^\complement }T_p\,d\mu\leqslant \mu(K)\leqslant 2\epsilon \,|\mu|(\mathbb{R}^k)-\int_{P^\complement }T_p\,d\mu\\
\implies |\mu(K)|\leqslant 2\epsilon |\mu|(\mathbb{R}^k)+\left| \int_{P^\complement }T_p\,d \mu  \right|\tag3
$$

Finally, as $|\mu|(\mathbb{R}^k)<\infty $ then for every $\epsilon >0$ there is some $N>0$ such that $|\mu|(P^\complement )<\epsilon $ when $p\geqslant N$, then for large enough $p$ we have the bound $\left|\int_{P^\complement }T_p\,d \mu \right|\leqslant \epsilon (\epsilon +1)$. This together with (3), and as $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary, we finally find that $\mu(K)=0$ for every compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^k$. As $\mu$ is a finite Borel measure its regular so every Borel set $\mathbb{R}^k$ can be approximated from below for compact sets, therefore $\mu$ is the zero measure.∎

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest proof of uniqueness uses the transform $u = \exp(-t),$ then the uniqueness for Laplace transform reduces to proving that if the integral of $p(x) h(x)$ on $[0, 1]$ for any polynomial $p(x),$ then $h(x) = 0.$ That can be proved in many ways (Stone-Weierstrass, Korovkin...).

Comment: how you do this transform if $t\in \Bbb R^k$?

Comment: @Masacroso Well, you could marginalize and use induction...

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "marginalizing" there?

Comment: Fix all but the last coordinate. Then you have an ordinary 1-d Laplace transform...

Comment: the measure is in $\Bbb R^k$, how you can define a one-dimensional measure???